# Mongoose: Join Operation, populate isn't possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, backend, populate

I'm currently struggling with a project of mine.

I've got a collection called "Games" and one "Participation".
When a user loggs in, he/she should be able to see the **games** and the individual participation status. 
Therefore, I want to join these two collections **but I can't use .populate() because I can't enter the neccessary Participation ID in the Games collection due to the fact, that I don't have the participation ID at the time I create a game.** (So I would need to save the participation, remember the created ID and insert THIS id in the games collection afterwards) 
The other way round would be a good solution (to populate Games in Participation) but initially, there are no participations in these collection, until a user clicks "Participate" or "Not Participate".

---

Basically I need a SQL query like that:

### `select * from games g, participation p where g.gamesId = p.gamesId AND p.username = [...]`

Is there any possibility to achieve this?
Otherwise I would need to save every participation as a "Game", having the dependent username and his/her participation status in it.
Wouldn't prefer this solution at all.

Thanks in advance!

In case it helps:
Here are my two collections:

Game:

```
var gameSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    isHome: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    time: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    uzeit: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    clubId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    enemy: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    place: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    (participation: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Teilnahme' }])
});
```

Participation:

```
var participationSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        playerAvailable: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        clubId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
        gameId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Game' },
        memberName: { type: String, required: true },
    }
);
```